# How is the esign agreement information handled/configured?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a situation when we send an envelope/package through DocuSign to a customer they are greeted with the checkbox to acknowledge an agreement to receive these documents via DocuSign.  When RecipientDelivered event happens that agreement information, along with the date the customer accepts, shows up in the XML(see example below) that is sent back to us.

```
...
        <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
        <EsignAgreementInformation>
                <AccountEsignId>00000-0000-0000-00000-0000000000</AccountEsignId>
                <UserEsignId>00000-0000-0000-00000-0000000000</UserEsignId>
                <AgreementDate>2019-04-20T15:11:48.77</AgreementDate>
        </EsignAgreementInformation>
        <RecipientId>00000-0000-0000-00000-0000000000</RecipientId>
...
```

However with successive Documents being sent, that agreement information no longer gets sent in the XML for RecipientDelivery.

Is there a configuration to be set that will force the EsignAgreementInformation to be always included in the XML that is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a separate endpoint in the API you can use this information:

```
GET {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes/{envelopeid}/recipients/{recipientid}/consumer_disclosure
```

The XML only shows this the first time a new signer signs a document as we don't ask the user to accept the eSign agreement more than once, but you can retrieve this information any time you want using the API above.